# Como criar um PrivateFontCollection

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho algumas fontes que não são padrões do Windows, então estou criando um `PrivateFontCollection` porém estou com dificuldades.

Essas fontes são usadas pelo programa todo, então pensei em criar uma `Classe Static` com um método `get`, porém como poderia adicionar as fontes ao `PrivateFontCollection`? sei que utilizamos o método `AddFontFile` então pensei em adicionar as fontes, logo apos o login do usuário, mas não estou conseguindo.

Classe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using DevExpress.CodeParser;

namespace Onee.Classes.Font
{
    public static class Fonts
    {
        private static PrivateFontCollection Font_collection;

        Font_collection.AddFontFile("C:\\Users\\thomas\\Documents\\Workspace\\Onee\\Onee Beta 1.10.16.2\\Onee\\Resources\\C_Light.otf");
        Font_collection.AddFontFile("C:\\Users\\thomas\\Documents\\Workspace\\Onee\\Onee Beta 1.10.16.2\\Onee\\Resources\\C_Bold.otf");

        public static PrivateFontCollection Collection
        {
            get { return Font.Fonts.Font_collection; }
        }
    }   
}
```

Form:

```
        private void set_font()
        {
            label4.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[1], 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            label_usuario.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[1], 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            label3.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[1], 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            label2.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[1], 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            label5.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[1], 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            label1.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[1], 12, FontStyle.Bold);

            button_servicos.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[0], 15);
            button_comercial.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[0], 15);
            button_certificados.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[0], 15);
            button_equipamentos.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[0], 15);
            button_compras.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[0], 15);
            simpleButton1.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[0], 15);
            simpleButton2.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[0], 15);
            button_opsistema.Font = new Font(Classes.Font.Fonts.Collection.Families[0], 15);
        }
```

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using DevExpress.CodeParser;

namespace Onee.Classes.Font
{
    public static class Fonts
    {
        private static PrivateFontCollection Font_collection = new PrivateFontCollection();

        public static void add_font()
        {
            Font_collection.AddFontFile("C:\\Users\\thomas\\Documents\\Workspace\\Onee\\Onee Beta 1.10.16.2\\Onee\\Resources\\C_Light.otf");
            Font_collection.AddFontFile("C:\\Users\\thomas\\Documents\\Workspace\\Onee\\Onee Beta 1.10.16.2\\Onee\\Resources\\C_Bold.otf");
        }

        public static PrivateFontCollection Collection
        {
            get { return Font.Fonts.Font_collection; }
        }
    }
}
```

Está certo essa abordagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas melhorias simples de implementar:

1. Use @ antes de uma string para interpretá-la literalmente. Isto ajuda em casos quando há muitos caracteres para escapar. Ex:

   ```
   Font_collection.AddFontFile("C:\\Meu\\Diretorio\\Super\\Obscuro");
   ```

   Vira:

   ```
   Font_collection.AddFontFile(@"C:\Meu\Diretorio\Super\Obscuro");
   ```
2. Se é necessário adicionar os fontes (método `add_font()`) somente uma vez, considere usar um [construtor estático](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

   ```
   static Fonts(){                    
       Font_collection = new PrivateFontCollection();
       Font_collection.AddFontFile(@"C:\Fonte\Um");
       Font_collection.AddFontFile(@"C:\Fonte\Dois");
   }
   ```
3. No seu forms não é necessário criar uma nova instância de `Font` para cada control! Crie uma para um estilo desejado e use-a em todos os controls que deseja que possue esta fonte.

Ainda, alguns outros itens da sua implementação são questionáveis (caminhos absolutos para referenciar um arquivo/recurso?), mas são muito abrangentes e fogem do escopo desta pergunta.

Comment: amigo, poderia me direcionar, ou me explicar sobre esses caminhos absolutos? fiz uma revisão no código, direcionando o caminho para o caminho da aplicação, utilizando `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel o problema de usar um caminho de arquivo absoluto é que isto torna seu programa menos portável. Imagine que você quer colocar seu novo programa em outro computador. Usando o código postado por você ele só funcionaria se você possuí-se um driver C:\, e neste driver existir uma pasta de usuários, e nesta pasta existir o usuário thomas, assim por diante... É bem mais fácil usar um diretório relativo a sua aplicação.